# Xcode how trim a string with special character $

Tags: trim, texttrimming

I've a string with this kind of value `/finocchi$FINOCCHamelo`

Now I need a new string with only this part of the word `FINOCCHamelo`

I've try this:

```
NSString * newString = [item.label stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""];
```

But it's not right becouse change the $ with blank char.
I need to filter the string afther $
How Can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in all the case you have only one $ in your string and you need the value after $.

```
NSArray *brokenStrings = [item.label componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];
NSString *filteredString = [brokenStrings objectAtIndex:1];
```

There are a lot more ways to do this: 
You can opt any one from these methods, or dozen other methods are available in NSString.

```
– componentsSeparatedByString:
– substringFromIndex:
- rangeOfString:
– stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
```